# Continuity and Semi-continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

$U=\{u=(x,y)\in R^2 : y\geq 0\}$
$J(u)= x^2+y^2$ for $x>0$ and $J(u)=0$ for $x\leq 0$
$U_1=\{(x,y): x>0, y\geq 0\}$

I have to show that $J$ is continuous on $U_1$ and semi-continuous on $U$.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean specifically lower semi-continuity.

$J(u)=x^2+y^2$ on $U_1$ because we have $x>0$ on $U_1$.  It follows that $J(u)$ is continuous on $U_1$.

To see lower semi-continuity, first notice that $J(u)$ is continuous at all points not on the $y$-axis, so it is lower semi-continuous at those points as well.  Hence, we only need to check points on the $y$-axis.

Now, let $p=(0,y_0)$ be a point on the $y$-axis, and fix $\epsilon>0$.  Notice that $J(p)=0$.  We wish to show there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $J(u)\ge J(p)-\epsilon=-\epsilon$ for all $u\in N$.  Since $J(u)\ge 0$ for all $u$, we can let $N$ be any neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Ok, great. Just, **"$J(u)$ is continuous at all points not on $y$-axis, so it is lower semi-continuous at those points as well."** This always holds? If it is continuous, then it is lower and upper semi-continuous both?

Comment: @user23709: A function is continuous at $u$ if and only if it is both upper and lower semi-continuous. So continuity at a point implies semi-continuity.